# Bootstrap 3 button-dropdown links are giving me a JQuery syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the example [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns) to get the following markup:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="/test/">Test Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Clicking the 'Action' button causes the popup to appear as expected. When I click on 'Test Link' I'm expecting to go to the `/test/` page but I'm getting the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /test/
at.error @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
mt @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
kt @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
at @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
x.fn.extend.find @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5
x.fn.x.init @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
x @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
c.show @ bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous function) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
x.extend.each @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
x.fn.x.each @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
b @ bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous function) @ (index):1508
x.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5
x.event.add.v.handle @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5
```

As well as this, the link that I clicked it is highlighted blue.

I haven't diverged much from the example so I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here. Why don't my links in button dropdowns work?

Edit: Some more information - I cannot post the whole HTML page since it's enormous and full of lots of irrelevant things. However, I did mock up a test page with the example bootstrap boilerplate and the link worked - suggesting there is something in my page which is causing a conflict. I'll reduce it until I find a minimal page that reproduces the error and post back.

The problem persists no matter what the link format is:

```
<a href="/test/">Test Link</a>
<a href="/test">Test Link</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Test Link</a>
<a href="?lang=en">Test Link</a>
```

All produce the same error (the last one is the one I'm eventually going to use).

Edit 2: Okay, the problem appears to be when I have the whole `<div>` inside a `<ul class="nav nav-tabs">`. This was hidden by layers of Django.

Comment: Show your entire HTML document.

Comment: would it be because you are not linking the page correctly in your href attribute? Im not sure, but I don't think you need / after test

Comment: It would be helpful to see more of the html, but it appears the link format is not correct, could you elaborate on the location of the page to which you are trying to link?

Comment: Seems like you're missing an opening quote on one of your links. Seeing as the 'test page' you created works fine, it's obviously a typo on the main page

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests `unrecognized expression: /test/` it is not able to identify the `href` value or it thinks `href` is invalid. If the `href` you are referring is in the same page just give that element's `id` as `href`.

**For ex**

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#sample">Test Link</a></li> <!--Pass it as reference to id-->
  </ul>
</div>
<!--Some more elements-->
....
<div id="sample">href you are referring</div>
```

Or if the `href` is an `url` and you think it should go to different page then give the absolute `url`.

**For ex:** If it is an `html` file then give it as

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="test/sample.html">Test Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

where `test` being the folder located in the place where your `html` stays and `sample.html` being the `filename` inside the folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<a data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">ButtonName<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li>
                <a onclick="window.location.href='b.php'"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

but actually you should make it like this

```
<button id="myButton" class="float-left submit-button" >Home</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "www.yoursite.com";
    };
</script>
```